# Upload Audio file to server using axios in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio, axios, upload

I'm trying to upload an audio file (wav) to the google cloud server in react-native. I'm using the [react-native-sound-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-recorder). I'm converting the file to a blob and adding it in the form-data I can console the encoded file and there is no error on front-end. But, when I send the form-data to the server it says file empty.
I would really appreciate the help.

```
const voiceSearchApi = async (form: any) => {
axios.post(apiUrl, form,
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  }
).then((res) => {
  console.log({ res: res.data });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err.response);
})

// return res
```

}

```
 const blobToBase64 = (blob) => {
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    resolve(reader.result);
  };
});
```

};

```
const stopRecording = async () => {
try {
  const result: { path: string } = await SoundRecorder.stop();
  console.log('Stopped recording:', result?.path);
  setIsRecording(false);
  setFilePath(result?.path);
  const temp = await readFile(result?.path)
  const audioURI = `file://${result?.path}`;
  const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", audioURI, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

  const operation: any = await blobToBase64(blob)
  console.log({ operation });
  // console.log({ blobFile: JSON.stringify(blobFile) });

  const formData = new FormData();
  const uriParts = result?.path.split('.');
  let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
  console.log({ fileType });

  formData.append('file', base64.encode(operation))
  const res = await voiceSearchApi(formData)
  // console.log({ temp });
  // const result2 = await res.text();
  // console.log({ result2 });
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Failed to stop recording:', err);
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I was facing something similar but I'm using expo.
I used **expo-av** for recording and **expo-file-system** for posting the audio file.

[POST an audio file to an API endpoint with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76160761/post-an-audio-file-to-an-api-endpoint-with-javascript?noredirect=1#comment134312018_76160761)

Comment: Appreciate the reply but I solved the issue . Turns out I needed to add transform request in the axios request. Once this was done the issue was solved.