# POST an audio file to an API endpoint with Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to POST a file already stored in the mobile device to this 3P shazam API to recognize the song. But I'm getting this error code:

> 422. 
>
> {“detail”:[{“loc”:[“body”,“file”],“msg”:“field  required”,“type”:“value_error.missing”}]}

API: https://rapidapi.com/tipsters/api/shazam-core

Endpoint: /v1/tracks/recognize

This is the info needed by the endpoint:

[image]

And this is how I'm trying the request.

```
let audioFile = new File([""], fileUri, {type: "audio/wav"});

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', audioFile);

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'MY_API_KEY',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com',
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    },
    body: data
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    console.log(response.status);
    const result = await response.text();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

Any other idea on how to make the call and send the audio file with JS?

Comment: `new File([""], fileUri, {type: "audio/wav"});` creates an empty file. How do you expect this to work?

Comment: And `FormData` creates "multipart/form-data" not "application/octet-stream". There is no need to explicitly set the "Content-Type" header.

Comment: @gre_gor what would be the way then? using fileReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using the **uploadAsync** method from **expo-file-system**

1. npm install expo-file-system
2. `import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';`
3. Posting the file

```
    const response = await FileSystem.uploadAsync(url, audioFileUri, {
      fieldName: 'file',
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': apiKey,
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com',
      }
    });
```